# How to execute npm in a Dockerfile for a dotnet project

Tags: node.js, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, dockerfile

## Issue

`docker build .` fails to find npm. See Dockerfile below.

### Strangeness

On 19 July, 2023 (and many dates before then) `docker build .` succeeded. I checked out the Git commit from 19 July today. `docker build .` fails today. I have tried the command on multiple computers. Fails everywhere.

## Questions

Is this the correct way to load node.js into a dotnet project?

Will you explain how I can execute npm from the dotnet build stage?

### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest AS node_base
# npm --version shows 9.8.0 so npm will execute in this stage
RUN npm --version

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY --from=node_base . .
# I expect `RUN npm --version` to work at this location. However it fails to find npm.
# Where is npm?
# find command shows npm at ./usr/local/bin/npm
RUN find . -name npm
# The following command fails. npm: not found
RUN ./usr/local/bin/npm --version
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with `npm`?  Can you do it in a dedicated build stage `FROM node`, and then `COPY` the resulting (static-file) output into your application?

Answer (score 1):

The npm command is looking for `node` and it does not find it (ie. its location is not in `PATH`).

Why don't you start from one of the image (say `aspnet`) and use `apt-get` to install the other packages (say `node`), you'll get a proper setup with the required environment variables.

Comment: MSFT provides a tutorial for using nod.js with dotnet in Docker at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-tools-react?view=vs-2022. I eliminated the node_base stage. I performed npm installation via apt.